# IIS 7.5 configuration sections fail to open

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I published an asp.net website and now i cannot open 'error pages' or any other configuration secton. the error i receive is " there was an error while performing this operation, details: filename:\?\inetpub\siteurl.co.za\web.config "

the website was working previously, the only change made was editing of rewrite module.

what could be the cause ? has anyone had the same issue before ?

Comment: Can you verify that if you remove the rewrite module section the site becomes operational again? If this is the case can you post the relevant section?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the rewrite module. it was installed, however IIS was not restarted therefore it did not recognize my web.config rewrite rules.